# How to get the selected values of jQuery multi select UI in codebehind?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, jquery-ui

I have the jQuery UI multiselect. I need the selected values on button click in the codebehind.

.aspx Page:

```
 <select id="countries" runat="server" class="multiselect" name="countries[]">
    </select>

    <asp:Button id="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="btn_OnClick"></asp:Button>
```

.cs Page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   countries.Attributes.Add("multiple", "multiple");
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      countries.Items.Add(i.ToString());
    }
 }

protected void btn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {   }​
```

Comment: what is languages here and countries is not runat="server" how you are accessing it please correct your code first

Comment: Also after making runat server check the view source how it is rendered

Comment: @AshirvadSingh : Its rendering fine. But i cant able to get the selected items

Comment: @rahul: Sorry. Now its corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.aspx Page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/page.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="css/ui.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="js/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/localisation/jquery.localisation-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/tmpl/jquery.tmpl.1.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.multiselect.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // remote
            $("#languages").multiselect({

            });

        });
    </script>




     <form target="submitFrame" runat="server">
<div>
       <dl>
           <dd>
          <select id="languages" class="multiselect" runat="server" name="languages[]">
           </select>
          </dd>
       </dl>
</div>
<div class="optionWrapper">
  <div class="optionInput">
    <input id="ec_checkValues" type="button" class="button" value="Assign Employees" />
     Selected Employees:
       <input id="hdn" type="text" />
   </div>
```

.cs Page:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        languages.Attributes.Add("multiple", "multiple");
        DataTable dt = obj.GetDataStoreInTable("Select top 10 intslno, nvrempname from tblHRIMS_employeedetail");
        languages.DataSource = dt;
        languages.DataTextField = "nvrempname";
        languages.DataValueField = "intslno";
        languages.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: This code can get your selected values in a textbox and then accessed from code behind page. This works 100% fine...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your select element to this (the options are just examples):

```
<select runat="server" id="countries" multiple="true" class="multiselect">
    <option label="1" value="1" />
    <option label="2" value="2" />
    <option label="3" value="3" />
    <option label="4" value="4" />
    <option label="5" value="5" />
</select>
```

You left out the runat="server", and the multiple property must be true instead of "multiple". ASP.NET will take care of the name attribute for you.

In the code behind, you will need to iterate through all of the select's items and check their selected property, like this:

```
protected void btn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (countries.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            // do something
            // countries.Items[i].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its saying that no items are selected

Comment: I guess since its getting postback i cant get the values.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: I was using test options within the select element that I have now added to the answer. Try using these values to test with and see if it works when you select multiple options. I'm not sure what jQuery plugin you are using for the multiselect, but it shouldn't change how the options are selected and submitted behind the scenes.

Comment: I binded the values at runtime in dropdown.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: Depending on how you're binding the options in the list, it could be affecting which values are coming up as selected in postback. Without seeing the code for how you are binding it's hard to say. There is an alternate way you can access posted values, however. You can directly call Request.Form[countries.UniqueID] to get a comma-separated string of which values were selected from the list, but this is not ideal.

Comment: Finally got the answer. used script to get the values and saved it in a hidden field.

Comment: I was wondering if the jquery ehynds multiselect plugin would keep the hidden original select in sync with the other displayed elements and it turns you're right; it was as simple as just accessing them normally.